# Couldn't find FoodObject without an ID

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, redis, e-commerce

I am trying to build a shopping cart feature in my rails app using redis, following [this tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/build-online-store-rails/).

**Problem**

The problem that I'm having when I wire everything together is the above error message, any ideas? I already have 5 FoodObject items in the db, and have been racking my brain trying to figure this out for past five hours.

**FoodObject Controller**

```
class FoodObjectsController < ApplicationController

    def menu
        @food = FoodObject.all
        @foodObj = FoodObject.find(params[:id])
        @cart_action = @foodObj.cart_action current_customer.try :id
    end

end
```

**FoodObject Model**

```
class FoodObject < ActiveRecord::Base
    def cart_action(current_customer_id)
      if $redis.sismember "cart#{current_customer_id}", id
        "Remove from"
      else
        "Add to"
      end
    end

end
```

**Menu.html.erb**

```
<%= render 'shared/header' %>

<div class="container menu-container">
    <% @food.each do |food| %>
        <div class = "col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-12 food_info">
            <img src="<%= food.imageurl %>">

            <p><%= food.name %> - $<%= food.price %></p>
            <p><%= food.description %></p>
            <%if signed_in?%>

              <%=link_to "", class: "button", data: {target: @cart_action, addUrl: add_to_cart_path(@foodObj), removeUrl: remove_from_cart_path(@foodObj)} do%>
                <i class="fi-shopping-cart"></i>
                <span><%=@cart_action%></span> Cart
              <%end%>
            <%end%>

        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>



<script>
    $(window).load ->
      $('a[data-target]').click (e) ->
        e.preventDefault()
        $this = $(this)
        if $this.data('target') == 'Add to'
          url = $this.data('addurl')
          new_target = "Remove from"
        else
          url = $this.data('removeurl')
          new_target = "Add to"
        $.ajax url: url, type: 'put', success: (data) ->
          $('.cart-count').html(data)
          $this.find('span').html(new_target)
          $this.data('target', new_target)

</script>

<%= render 'shared/footer' %>
```

I would appreciate any help I can get on this issue, thanks!!

Full Trace:

```
activerecord (4.0.8) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:267:in `find_with_ids'
activerecord (4.0.8) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:36:in `find'
activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3) lib/active_record/deprecated_finders/relation.rb:122:in `find'
activerecord (4.0.8) lib/active_record/querying.rb:3:in `find'
app/controllers/food_objects_controller.rb:5:in `menu'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in `_run__770126353706210109__process_action__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.8) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.0.8) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:676:in `call'
omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:59:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.8) lib/active_record/migration.rb:373:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__4091681657315170613__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.0.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.8) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/Users/abhasarya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/abhasarya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/abhasarya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: A stack trace would be very helpful. Looking at your code, my best guess is that in your FoodController class `params[:id]` is `nil`, and the exception is being thrown by `FoodObject.find(params[:id])`.  It's hard to say without a stack trace though.

Comment: Hey, as it is already been said, please add stack trace in the question. Also I'm not really sure hitting what url causes the error?

Comment: I added the trace @RoaringStones

Comment: what about the url which causes the error?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in your view you're using `@foodObj` in your link when maybe you want to be using `food` from the block argument.